# Simple Python program to convert roman numerals to the international system

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried to put together a basic program to convert roman numbers to conventional numbers and I seem to have made some mistake and right now it's a hit or miss.Do take a look at the code.I've described it better in the code as comments.Thanks!

```
def roman(roman_num):
inter_dic = {
    "I":1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100,"D":500,"M":1000
    }
output = 0
num = roman_num.upper()
#this is to ensure that the number appears as uppercase alphabets

for numeral in num:
    numeral_index = num.index(numeral)
#I've squeezed an exception here to handle the last digit in the number
    try:
        #for the additive part
        if inter_dic[numeral] > inter_dic[num[numeral_index + 1]]:
            output += inter_dic[numeral]
        #for the subtraction part
        elif inter_dic[numeral] < inter_dic[num[numeral_index + 1]]:
            output -= inter_dic[numeral]
        
        elif inter_dic[numeral] == inter_dic[num[numeral_index + 1]]:
            output += inter_dic[numeral]
        #the following line is actually dead code,but I've added it just in case.
        else:
            print("There was an error.")
    #the IndexError will be called when the last digit is reached and so the last digit 
    #will be added

    except IndexError:
        output += inter_dic[numeral]
          
return output


assert roman("cxcix") == 199
#this returns an assertion error
#when the function is called,the output is 179
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
def roman(roman_num):
    inter_dic = {
        "I":1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100,"D":500,"M":1000
        }
    x = list(map(lambda x: inter_dic[x], roman_num.upper()))
    for idx in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[idx+1] > x[idx]:
            x[idx] *= -1
    return x

decimal = roman("cxcix")
print(decimal) # Output: [100, -10, 100, -1, 10]
print(sum(decimal)) # Output: 199
```

This works on the assumption that the numbers are properly structured. As in, the numbers represented should be in order of the biggest to the smallest.

---

The above code will work even if you just give it one character, because the loop is based on the `range(len() - 1)` of the given list that is created when we translate the letters into their integers.

If `x == [100]` then `len(x)-1 == 0` which will just terminate the for-loop immediately, so we will not encounter any `IndexError` inside of the loop.

---

To explain what is happening in your code that differs from my version we can create a simple example here:

```
lst = list("abcabc")
for idx, letter in enumerate(lst):
    print(f"Letter: {letter}, list.index: {lst.index(letter)}, Actual index: {idx}")
```

Output:

```
Letter: a, list.index: 0, Actual index: 0
Letter: b, list.index: 1, Actual index: 1
Letter: c, list.index: 2, Actual index: 2
Letter: a, list.index: 0, Actual index: 3
Letter: b, list.index: 1, Actual index: 4
Letter: c, list.index: 2, Actual index: 5
```

If we look at the documentation for `list.index`, we can see this description:

```
index(self, value, start=0, stop=2147483647, /)
    Return first index of value.

    Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
```

So because there are repeated values inside of `lst` when we call to check for it's index, it just returns the first value that matches the variable we give it.